# Is it possible to update link to a renamed armature?

Tags: rigging, armature, blend-files

I was curious to know if it's possible to update a link to an armature after you renamed it in the original .blend file. I had to change its name for the sake of organization, but I haven't been able to discover a solution, and all the animation channels that hold my animation keyframes are naturally not connecting and updating. I was not able to find the answer to this specific question online, let alone discover a solution. I know Blender has a few quirks with linking libraries so please advise and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So the best solution I discovered was to copy the animation data from one object to another. Since the missing armature proxy still held all the frames (and all the bones had the same name), it was a simple process. Just had to select both objects in the correct order for data transfer, then hit object > make links > animation data.